# Django query in multiple tables without foreign key

Tags: python, mysql, django

My models look like this

```
class Trans(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=60)
    sys = models.ManyToManyField(Sys)
    flag = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)

class Sys(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=64)
    mid = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    numbers = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    org = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to get **org** and **numbers** by mid in Trans and use them in templete like this

```
{% for row in rowlist %}
    {{ row.mid }}  //in Trans
    {{ row.flag }}  //in Trans
    {{ row.org }}  //in Sys when mid=Trans.mid
    {{ row.numbers }}//in Sys when mid=Trans.mid
```

SQL shoule be

```
SELECT Sys.numbers, Sys.org FROM Sys, Trans WHERE Trans.mid = Sys.mid
```

How to make query like this in Django?
And I tried

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * From trans, sys")
rowlist = cursor.fetchone()
```

which return what I need but is turple

Comment: Why you doenst have a foreingkey? o_o

Comment: I can't use mid as primary key because it's not unique,if I use foreign key,should I set index in two models first?

Comment: If it is not unique, then db can have many-to-many relationship between those tables. So, you can have a manytomany field in django.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why u are doing this, but,
I think this can solve your problem:

```
mid_list = Trans.objects.values_list('mid', flat=True)
rowlist = Sys.objects.filter(mid__in=mid_list)
```

## Edit 1

```
class Trans(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=60)
    sys = models.ManyToManyField(Sys, through='TranSys')
    flag = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)

class Sys(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=64)
    mid = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    numbers = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    org = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

class TranSys(models.Model):
    trans = models.Foreingkey(Trans)
    sys = models.ForeignKey(Sys)
```

Now, just use :

```
rowlist = TranSys.objects.values('sys__org', 'sys__numbers','sys__mid','trans__flag')
```

Comment: I edited it again,sorry for my unclear question.I wanna get mid and flag in Trans as well as numbers and org in Sys by mid.I can't see mid in your answer, thanks

Comment: try it rowlist = TranSys.objects.values('trans__org', 'trans__numbers', 'trans__flag', 'sys__mid')

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to make it a Foreign Key, because it should be.

You can do something like this.

```
trans_mid = Trans.objects.values('mid')
syss = Sys.objects.filter(mid__in=trans_mid)
```

Also, you can use [raw_sql](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries) to perform such query.

Comment: I have edit my model to manytomany field but still don't know how to get numbers/org

Answer (score 0):

It'd better, if you made mid as a `ForeignKey` in `Sys` class.
So you can directly access like;

```
sys_list = Sys.objects.filter(
    mid__in=Trans.objects.values('mid')
).values('numbers', 'org')
```